# Tiered SQL results array made up of two seperate queries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Looking to create a results array from an SQL table consisting of two sorts of memberships i.e. "gold" and "normal". This will be paginated into 10 results per page, with "gold" members taking spots 1-3 and "normal" 4-10.

However once we approach the last page or 1st initially with low member count we may have "gold" just assume position 1 and "normal" 2-6 (7 total results on last page say).

Firstly, can this type or sort be achieved through SQL and how?

Secondly, If not I'd have to run a PHP for loop to sort I assume. For 1-3 take from query1, for 4-10 take from query2, etc. Any idea's here if this is appropriate?

Comment: Yes it can be achieved, altough you'll probably going to need 2 queries...

Comment: Okay so you are pointing me into the direction or two queries, get the total count then for 1-3 take from query 1, 4-10 take from query 2, 11-13 take again from query 1 and so on...? Via PHP or SQL?

Comment: Something like that, I think it's even possible to do it in 1 query, not sure since I don't know full DB structure.. But you could combine the 2 queries if they give the same result..MaybeUnion does the trick?

Comment: What happens if there are 40 "silver" in the database and no "gold"? 7 of them on first page with 6 pages total or 10 per page with 4 pages total?

Comment: 10 per page 4 pages total Kuba - Laravel paginator will do this part for me I think, it's really how to sort the data [1 to 3]"gold"[4-10]"normal"[11-13]"gold"[14-20]"normal and so on OR if only 1 gold member [1]"gold"[2-10]"normal"

Comment: So not only do your queries need to select proper rows from each category, but also should be aware whether proper rows from the other category exist for particular page (and previous pages).

Comment: Yes this should be able to be done by a resultsperpage variable used for both the query and later paginator

Comment: And when there are only 7 "gold" and 3 "normal" one should see only one page with 7 gold on top and 3 normal on bottom?

Comment: Yeah - that's correct Kuba

Comment: Can't you `select ... order by... limit 10` from `select ... union` to replace two queries with one?